# Why do I get an "Unexpected character '@'" parsing error when I run ESLint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm getting this parsing error (*i.e.*, `error Unexpected character '@' ParseError`) returned when running `eslint --cache --fix`. I'm not sure why I'm seeing this error though, since I don't have an '@' anywhere near that line that's being flagged as problematic. The following is a snippet of my code where the issue is happening:

```
const getCustomerInformation = async (id, role) => {
    return await gql
        .query({
            query: GET_CUSTOMER_DATA,
            variables: {
                id
            }
        })
        .then((res) => {
            response[role] = res
        })
}
```

`GET_CUSTOMER_DATA` is being imported from another file and is as follows:

```
export const GET_CUSTOMER_DATA = gql`
    query getCustomerInformation($id: String!) {
        OSDTGetCustomerInformation(id: $id) {
            ... on CustomerSuccess {
                id
                fullName
            }
            ... on CustomerError {
                message
            }
        }
    }
`
```

The line that's being flagged as problematic is `query: GET_CUSTOMER_DATA` at character 42 in the 1st code block. As mentioned earlier though, I don't see an instance of '@' being used, so I'm not sure why there's a linting issue. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me understand what could be the issue here.

FWIW, I'm using ESLint v7.31.0.

Comment: can you please provide [mcve] including what versions and config you have?

Comment: is `GET_CUSTOMER_DATA` just a regular variable (i.e declared using `var`, `let` or `const`)?

Comment: Yes @Bravo, `GET_CUSTOMER_DATA` is being declared using `const`.

Comment: what does `order` do - not sure a modern linter would be confused by tagged template literals - but if you're right about which line is the issue, then something must be happening that confuses the linter

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that @Bravo. I accidentally swapped out `gql` and replaced it with `order` when I was trying to 'anonymize' my code. `gql` is a template literal tag that can be used to concisely write a GraphQL query that is parsed into a standard GraphQL AST.

Comment: the function name isn't the relevant thing - I wanted to know what the function DOES not what it IS, as I do understand tagged templates - again, I doubt it's the issue, but the linter thinks there's an `@` there when there clearly is not :p

Comment: Out of curiosity: what happens if you copy-paste the ````gql`...` ```` in place of `GET_CUSTOMER_DATA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the pre-commit linter was recognizing that I hadn't added any documentation for `getCustomerInformation()`. So, the linter attempted to solve this by adding a comment with `getCustomerInformation()`'s parameters (*i.e.*, id & role) that included '@'. However, the linter wasn't adding them in the right place — which is what was throwing the parsing error. So, I had to manually add documentation. I added the following above where `getCustomerInformation()` is being defined:

```
/**
* @param {string} id
* @param {string} role
*/
```